# Laptop goes to sleep randomly when turned on

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I have dual booted Linux with ubuntu and windows 10. Everything seems to be fine on the windows side, but when I try to use ubuntu, laptops go to sleep randomly, and weirdly when I press the power button, it continues from where I left off. For example, the laptop goes randomly to sleep on the ubuntu loading animation screen and when I turn on the power, it resumes from that very screen. This happens on a full battery and even when my laptops plugged in.

Comment: Check your power management settings for 'when power button is pressed' and 'put computer to sleep when'

Comment: Settings look fine, Automatic suspend happens 20 minutes on standby. Even if that was the case, would the system count startup as a standby period? So, I don't think that's the issue.